# Displaying wordpress custom post type as gallery with links

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have created a page template to display all thumbnails for a custom post type, the issue I'm having is i can get the page to show the thumbnails but I can't get those thumbnails to link to the original image which would then load in a lightbox with a rel="lightbox" tag. If anyone can help it would be awesome:

```
foreach($posts->posts as $user_image){

  $user_info = get_userdata($user_image->post_author);    

  $user_image_cats = get_the_terms($user_image->ID, 'image_category');

  foreach($user_image_cats as $cat){

    $user_image_cat = $cat->name;

  }

  $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($user_image->ID);   
$
  $out .= '<a href="(wp_get_attachment_link($post_thumbnail_id))">';
  $out .=  wp_get_attachment_image($post_thumbnail_id, 'thumbnail', $permalink);         
  $out .= '</a>';

}

echo $out;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting the attachment link using `wp_get_attachment_link($post_thumbnail_id)` you need to pass the image size into the second parameter. If you don't pass the image size you would like the link for, it will default to getting the link for the thumbnail version of the image.

So instead of

```
wp_get_attachment_link($post_thumbnail_id)
```

You would need

```
wp_get_attachment_link($post_thumbnail_id, "full")
```

**EDIT**

The code is being printed because you have used it inside some quotes without breaking out of them first, the line you would need would be something like

```
$out .= '<a href="'.(wp_get_attachment_link($post_thumbnail_id, "full")).'">';
```

Notice that the function you are trying to use is now surrounded by `'.` and `.'`. What this does is breaks out of the quotes and then concatenates the value returned by the function to the end of `<a href="`, we then break back into the quotes and concatenate `">` onto the end giving us a final result of

```
<a href="[URL_HERE]">
```

Comment: Thanks I've tried that but to no avail, I think I must have some quotes or something in the wrong place because its printing that line as code not getting the link at all?